# Why the data did not appear when I put bracket () after THEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

There are condition in my code: if the age of employee 50 and above, he will receive 'ESP1' medical benefit. If the age of employee 35-50 years old, he will receive 'ESP' medical benefit.

For the employee who 50 and above, their screen shouldn't view 'ESP'.
This is my code:

```
Select sh_benefitclaimtype.description,      
        'entitlement'= case when sh_medicalentitlement.amount = 9999 then 'N/A'    
                            when  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = 'BG' then 'RM300 per baby(Female)'    
                            when  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = 'CC' then 'RM200 per deceased'    
                    else convert(nvarchar,sh_medicalentitlement.amount)    
       end,    
        convert(decimal(15,2),isnull(#appr.appramt,0.00))as 'appramt',              
        convert(decimal(15,2),isnull(#pend.pendamt,0.00)) as 'pendamt',           
        'balance' = case when sh_medicalentitlement.amount = 9999 then 'N/A'    
                         when sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid in ('BG','CC') then 'N/A'    
                    else convert(nvarchar,sh_medicalentitlement.amount - isnull(#appr.appramt,0))    
       end,
       'benefitclaimid' = sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid
   From sh_medicalentitlement   
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #appr    
   ON sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = #appr.benfid    
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #pend    
   ON sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = #pend.benfid    
   LEFT OUTER JOIN is_empstatus  
   ON is_empstatus.jobgradeid = sh_medicalentitlement.jobgradeid     
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sh_benefitclaimtype    
   ON sh_medicalentitlement.regisno = sh_benefitclaimtype.regisno    
   and sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid    
   Where sh_medicalentitlement.regisno = @RegNo      
   And is_empstatus.empid = @EmpID      
   And dateadd(year,sh_benefitclaimtype.minage,@BirthDate) <= @date 
   AND sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid = CASE WHEN (datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) >=50) then (select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP') else  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid end   
   Order by sh_benefitclaimtype.description + space(180) + sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid
   end
```

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with brackets?

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough. What I mean is, the bracket after THEN

Comment: Can you post the full query, with good formatting?  It looks strange to me to have a subquery as the predicate of a `CASE` expression.

Comment: I has edited the post

Comment: Here (select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP')  multiple rows effecting so its wrong ,use top 1 in

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a specific error message?  I see one potential problem:

```
SELECT benefitclaimid FROM sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP')
```

Your THEN condition for > 50 years old must return a scalar result.  If the sub-query above returns more than one row, this will error out.

Comment: I didn't get any error however there are no data display. There should display all medical benefit except ESP. I did not know how to do the condition there

Answer (score 0):

AND sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid = CASE WHEN (datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) >=50) then (select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP')

If the query "select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP'" is returning more than one record then use "IN" instead of "=" as below

AND sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid IN CASE WHEN (datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) >=50) then (select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP')

Comment: I have tried your solution however it returns error 'an expression of non-boolean type specified is a context where a condition is expected'

Answer (score 0):

Use the below condition in select statement and check what is the output. My guess is, it is returning either null or unexpected value.

CASE WHEN (datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) >=50) then (select benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid <>'ESP') else  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid end

Comment: I did try and it returns syntax error. Should put = there I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select sh_benefitclaimtype.description,      
            'entitlement'= case when sh_medicalentitlement.amount = 9999 then N'N/A'    
                                when  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = 'BG' then N'RM300 per baby(Female)'    
                                when  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = 'CC' then 'RM200 per deceased'    
                        else convert(nvarchar(20),sh_medicalentitlement.amount)    
           end,    
            convert(decimal(15,2),isnull(#appr.appramt,0.00))as 'appramt',              
            convert(decimal(15,2),isnull(#pend.pendamt,0.00)) as 'pendamt',           
            'balance' = case when sh_medicalentitlement.amount = 9999 then N'N/A'    
                             when sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid in ('BG','CC') then N'N/A'    
                        else convert(nvarchar,sh_medicalentitlement.amount - isnull(#appr.appramt,0))    
           end,
           'benefitclaimid' = sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid
       From sh_medicalentitlement   
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #appr    
       ON sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = #appr.benfid    
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #pend    
       ON sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = #pend.benfid    
       LEFT OUTER JOIN is_empstatus  
       ON is_empstatus.jobgradeid = sh_medicalentitlement.jobgradeid     
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sh_benefitclaimtype    
       ON sh_medicalentitlement.regisno = sh_benefitclaimtype.regisno    
       and sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid = sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid    
       Where sh_medicalentitlement.regisno = @RegNo      
       And is_empstatus.empid = @EmpID      
       And dateadd(year,sh_benefitclaimtype.minage,@BirthDate) <= @date 
       AND sh_benefitclaimtype.benefitclaimid = (CASE 
                 WHEN (datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) >=50) then (select TOP(1) benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid ='ESP1') 
                 WHEN datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date) between 35 and 50 then (select TOP(1) benefitclaimid from sh_benefitclaimtype WHERE benefitclaimid ='ESP')
          else  sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid end )  
       Order by sh_benefitclaimtype.description + space(180) + sh_medicalentitlement.benefitclaimid
```

Comment: Thank you santoshkumar. Your solution did return only ESP. However , I want to display other benefits except ESP for employee >= 50 years old. Maybe my question not clear enough but many thanks

Comment: I have updated query so you can check and let me know !

Comment: Oh sorry for late. I did try, but the query only returns one row which is ESP1 for employee 50 and above. It should appear other benefits as well except ESP.

Comment: In case my comment confusing you, actually it should returns multiple rows.

Comment: Hi , i think   this "datediff(year,@BirthDate,@date)"  query  creating issue its returns only one value(age above 50) so only  'esp 1' condition is satisfying . Try to use date column in date function not @variables

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that's the reason. Anyway thanks santoshkumar for helping me.